# Comma in macro parameters

Tags: macros, comma-separated-list

I have a macro accepting several optional arguments in a comma separated list.
I would like to assign a value containing a comma to a particular argument. Is there a way to "escape" this particular comma so that it will not be interpreted as the beginning of a new argument.

Here is an except of what I would like to achieve:

```
\begin{mymacro}[arg1=a,b,arg2=c]
% ...
\end{mymacro}
```

I would like to set `arg1` to `a,b` and not, of course, seeing this interpreted as "`arg1=a` and `b`".

Thanks!

Comment: `[arg1={a,b},arg2=c]`

Comment: From the [`xkeyval` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xkeyval/doc/xkeyval.pdf) (p 9): "When you want to use *commas* or *equality signs* in the value of a key, surround the value by braces, as shown in the example: `\setkeys[my]{familya}{keya={some=text,other=text}}`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I guess that was a trivial question...

The answer is:

```
[arg1={a,b},arg2=c]
```

@Qrrbrbirlbel: thanks.